# Symfony2 Installation problems

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 and I'm trying to create a new project in my local environment following the steps listed in the Symfony book:

**Download**

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar install
```

**Create Project** (path relative to /var/www/)

```
$ php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition grupo76/final/ Symfony 2.5.*
```

***1st Problem*: I have to add /web/ to paths**

So, now I have to test the configuration by hitting

```
http://localhost/grupo_76/final/config.php
```

I get a 404, and have to change the address to

```
http://localhost/grupo_76/final/web/config.php
```

It complains about permissions on **/app/logs** and **/app/cache** but that's ok. I ran

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\ -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

***2nd Problem*: app_dev.php is completely broken**

Then, the book suggest I should hit

```
http://localhost/grupo_76/final/app_dev.php
```

but, again, I need to add **/web/**

```
http://localhost/grupo_76/final/web/app_dev.php
```

The page renders, but full of errors like this **No route found for "GET /"**

Please, see attachment.

[image: [IMG]app_dev.php[/IMG]]

I'm running:

- Apache2
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Hi! I'm running Apache 2

Comment: Ok ! Try pointing your initial folder to the web folder in a .htacess file.
You will have : http://localhost/grupo_76/final/config.php to give you the correct page. after that try again and let's try to solve it together.

Comment: also .. try to clear your cache, if you have an older installation of symfony2 `cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: did you have correctly configurate your host ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st Problem

You have to configure a web server. There is an official documentation for configuring web server for both Apache and Nginx. What you are doing is accessing `app_dev.php` or `config.php` from your localhost host relatively. See:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

#### 2nd Problem

You have to define routing for your / path (homepage, in other words). See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm unable to test it atm. I understand that some configuration can be required, what I don't understand is why the installation guide is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual-host won't help you, I already tried that, my working solution is:

1- Delete the old Symfony installation

2- Install a fresh one as **root** (`sudo su`)

3- Grant permissions to `/var/www/html` with `chmod 777 -R /var/www/html`"

Just take in count that you may want to readjust the folder's permissions when you get it working, to your specific scenario.